# Python sort based on 2 class attributes

Tags: python, sorting

Edit: just found out that I'm using py 2.6.2 (work installed so I can't do much about that)

So I'm trying to find the best way to sort a list based on 2 different class attributes

This list is basically some info for moving people from room to room in a company where some people might be part of a chain move 
(i.e. Joe Blow has to move before we can move Jane Doe into Joe's spot and Jane has to move before John Wick can move into Jane's spot etc.)

I get all the info something like below but there can also be people that aren't part of the chain move like Dan Man in the example below.

```
John Wick 303.10 -> 415.09
Dan Man 409.08 -> 221.02
Joe Blow 225.06 -> 512.01
Jane Doe 415.09 -> 225.06
```

I have all the relevant info split into a class with

```
startRoom
endRoom
originalString
```

So that part isn't an issue but when I try to "brute force" sort it like below: (Note, I do the list(chains) as it is previously a set to make sure I don't get doubles in there)

```
def sortChains():
    global chains
    #convert the set of chains to a list for list functions

    chains = list(chains)
    for x, move1 in enumerate(chains):
        for y, move2 in enumerate(chains):
            if move1.startRoom == move2.endRoom:
                temp = chains[y]
                chains.remove(move2)
                chains.insert(x,temp)
                continue
```

My problem is the sorting. One part of the problem is finding the person that is at the start of the chain and then sorting correctly after that. 
Any ideas/help is totally appreciated. And yes I know a double loop while moving stuff in the loop isn't the best but it's been the best I could think of at the time.

Comment: How would you sort `[(A, 1, 2), (B, 2, 1)]`?

Comment: Do the chains need to stay grouped? Or outputting `Joe -> Dan -> Jane -> John` in you example is ok?

Comment: @Adirio would be fine cause I have another loop to go through and add a spacer between chains (cause there can be multiple)

Comment: Can you ensure that: 1) All given moves are doable (i.e. there are no 2 endRoom with the same value) 2) There are no circular movements (e.g. A moves to B's place, B moves to C's place and C moves to A's place) for any number of persons

Comment: Take into account that if person A moves from a to b, then from b to c, and person B moves from d to b this is not complying 1). However, this is still a valid move as A will end in c and B in b.

Comment: There isn't usually any "cyclical" moves but they do happen from time to time. We usually notice those though so that's not an issue usually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to create a dependency graph and determine (a) which person has to move `before` some other person can move, and (b) which persons can move right now. We can use a 1:1 mapping here, but in the more general case, you might have to use a 1:n, n:1, or n:m mapping.

```
moves = {"John Wick": ("303.10", "415.09"),
         "Dan Man":   ("409.08", "221.02"),
         "Joe Blow":  ("225.06", "512.01"),
         "Jane Doe":  ("415.09", "225.06")}
# or dict((move.originalString, (move.startRoom, move.endRoom)) for move in list_of_moves)

# mapping {initial room -> name}
rooms = {start: name for (name, (start, end)) in moves.items()}
# Python 2.6: dict((start, name) for (name, (start, end)) in moves.items())

# mapping {moves_first: moves_after}
before = {rooms[end]: name for name, (start, end) in moves.items() if end in rooms}
# Python 2.6: dict((rooms[end], name) for name, (start, end) in moves.items() if end in rooms)

# persons that can move now
can_move = set(moves) - set(before.values())
```

Now, we can see who can move, move that person, and then update the persons who can move based on what person had to wait for that person to move, if any.

```
result = []
while can_move:
    # get person that can move, add to result
    name = can_move.pop()
    result.append(name)
    # add next to can_move set
    if name in before:
        can_move.add(before.pop(name))
```

Afterwards, `result` is `['Joe Blow', 'Jane Doe', 'John Wick', 'Dan Man']`

Complexity should be O(n), but of course, this will fail if there are cyclic dependencies.

Comment: Definitely closer with the edit. now saying that list doesn't have attribute .items  I just tried doing enumerate(moves) as well instead but says TypeError: iteration over non-sequence.  Same error if I just remove .items as well...so close
Edit: Also, just to clarify as well, the start/end in the  code above should be my startRoom/endRoom correct?

Comment: @TEvashkevich What does `type(moves)` say? It should be a `dict`, not a `list`. Did you define a function `dict`, shadowing the `dict` bultin function?

Comment: Ah, I was making it a list cause my stuff is just read in from a txt file and I put it in the class that I was talking about earlier. I guess I could potentially just re write to throw into a dict

Comment: @TEvashkevich See another edit for how to create the dict from a list of `Move` objects.

Comment: Oh nice I didn't know you could do that to just make a dictionary!
Thanks a ton man you've totally fixed my conundrum

Answer (score 0):

```
def do(moves):
    """RETURNS: [0] Sequence of persons to move.
                [1] Remainder
    """
    # (following line copied from 'tobias_k', replaced 'rooms' with 'current_db')
    # map: target position to person who occupies it
    current_db = { start: name for (name, (start, end)) in moves.items() }
    # maintain set of persons who are free to move to their target location
    liberated_set = set()
    # map occupier of a location -> set of people who would take his place.
    liberation_db = defaultdict(set)
    # whosoever wants to move to a free place -> liberated.
    # else                                    -> liberation_db
    for name, (start, end) in moves.items():
        occupier = current_db.get(start)
        if occupier is None: liberated_set.add(name)
        else:                liberation_db[occupier].add(name)

    sequence = []
    while liberated_set:
        # add people to the sequence who are free to move
        sequence.extend(liberated_set)
        # get new set of people who are free to move to their target
        # because their target position is no longer occupied.
        new_liberated_set = set()
        for occupier in liberated_set:
            if not occupier in liberation_db: continue
            new_liberated_set.extend(liberation_db[occupier])
            del liberation_db[occupier]
        liberated_set = new_liberated_set

     return sequence, set(liberation_db.values())
```

Comment: For both yours and Tobias's
     rooms = {start: name for(name, (start, end)) in moves.items()}
causes invalid syntax at the for keyword

Comment: @TEvashkevich Then you are using a _really_ old version of Python, probably 2.6 or older. See my edit.

Comment: Could you add a few lines what this is doing differently/better than my version?

Comment: @tobias_k just checked and you're right. It's 2.6.2 apparently (thought I was using a more current version but not my decision unfortunately)

Comment: @tobias_k I just mentioned you for the *first line* which I simply copied. The remainder obviously differs.

Comment: @Frank-ReneSchäfer Yes, it differs, I did not mean to imply plagiarism. I just think that this answer would very much benefit from a short description of what that code does, and why. Add least add a few comments.

Comment: Ah, now I see, yours seems to be a 1:n version of my 1:1 algorithm. Neat. But given the rooms-example, could there ever be a case where this is needed, i.e. where one person having moved in another room would enable two or more others to move?